# Does Amazon.com download code work everywhere?

Tags: origin, fifa-14

I have a gift coupon at amazon.com (not redeemable in the Indian website), and I want to buy Fifa 14 with it. However, I live in India with an Indian origin account, so will the download code I get from amazon.com work here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out all you have to do is enter a US address and it'll work. Won't work for a non US address.